# Json takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am getting an error where im giving 1 argument but it say's 2 were given, the end goal is to have the json body printed

```
url_get = 'http://ludwig.corp.podiumdata.com:/qdc/entity/v1/getEntities?type=EXTERNAL&count=2&sortAttr=name&sortDir=ASC'
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url_cookie, auth=(username,password), verify=False)
print('--------------------- 1. status_code ----------------------------------')
print(r.status_code)
print('--------------------- 1. headers ----------------------------------')
print(r.headers)
print('--------------------- 1. content ----------------------------------')
data = r.json(url_get)
print(data)
print('--------------------- 1. cookies ----------------------------------')
print(session.cookies, r.cookies)
print('--------------------- 1. cookies get_dict ----------------------------------')
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
print("7")
```

````
  File "<ipython-input-36-b971c3b17ea5>", line 67, in <module>
    data = r.json(url_get)

TypeError: json() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```
````

Comment: You're calling `json.loads` on a `string`, are you sure that's what you want? Rather than `data = r.json()`?

Comment: Yes you are correct let me update

Comment: Close, `r.json()` doesn't take any parameters, it's a method on the `r` object, so you don't need to hand it anything

Comment: The parameters given are ```self``` and ```url_get```. ```r.json()``` does not expect any arguments to be passed as the request object will have the response body already and just needs to parse it to json

Comment: `Response.json` takes one argument, and `r.json()` is equivalent to `Response.json(r)`.

Comment: You *already* "got" the URL; `r` is the response of that request.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses everyone, I understand the fix and have learned something new!! Follow up question though... so after I make this change it goes back to telling JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) , and JSONDecodeError: expecting value, is this because i have to decode the json into utf-8 or has that nothing to do with it

Comment: also the r variable references url_cookie in it, and i am trying to call another variable i have set called url_get that has the url to the json....this is why i thought putting the url_get into the json func was the correct thing to do originally

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are attempting to call `json.loads` on a url, which does not fit any valid object in python.

```py
import json

x = json.loads('[1, 2, 3]')
x  # This gets evaluated to a list
[1, 2, 3]

y = json.loads('hi i am a string')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm sure that error message looks familiar :)

Next, when you call the `json` method on a `Request` object, you don't need to pass it anything, since the body of the request will implicitly be passed to a `json` parser:

```py
r = requests.get(some_url)
r.json() # don't put anything in the parens here
```

The docs for `json` are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and `requests` are [here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Comment: You are thinking of the builtin json package. The user is using Requests and calling `json()` on a response object. That is a different scenario.

Comment: @rje if you go back through the edit history of the question, OP was originally asking about the builtin `json` package :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses everyone, I understand the fix and have learned something new!! Follow up question though... so after I make this change it goes back to telling JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) , and JSONDecodeError: expecting value, is this because i have to decode the json into utf-8 or has that nothing to do with it

Comment: So you can check the content using `r.content`, which should be a byte-string. If it is not valid json, then the `json()` method will raise an exception because it cannot resolve the content to a dictionary or similar structure

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say `r.json()`. `r` is the response object that represents the data returned from the server. Calling the `json()` method on that (tries to) parse the data from JSON into a python data structure. You cannot pass any extra arguments to that function.